# Azure DocumentClient thread safety

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is `DocumentClient` thread safe?

I get mixed messages:

From MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.aspx :

> Any public static ( Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

From MS blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1-2/ :

> SDK Usage Tip #1: Use a singleton DocumentDB client for the lifetime of your application Note that each DocumentClient instance is thread-safe and performs efficient connection management and address caching when operating in Direct Mode. To allow efficient connection management and better performance by DocumentClient, it is recommended to use a single instance of DocumentClient per AppDomain for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. We are aware of this issue and I have reported this to our documentation team. This a bug in the documentation tool that we use to generate the docs. I'll follow up with them on the status.

Yes, DocumentClient is thread-safe.

Regards,
Rajesh